# I am unsure: Is this an anti-join?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am working on the first problem of the famous SQLzoos and am working on the `using Null` section: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Using_Null

The question is:

> List the teachers who have NULL for their department.

The corresponding SQL query would be:

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM teacher t
WHERE t.dept IS NULL
```

Is this a type of anti-join? Specifically, is this a left-anti-join?

Comment: A join requires two tables.

Comment: That's not a join at all, that's a simple select statement.

Comment: anti join is when you have 2 tables and you have to use a "not in" to select elements from table 1 that does not exists in table 2. As the "not in" is very slow, it is better to use a left anti join.

Comment: But the output is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a join at all.

The statement is filtering only records for teachers who don't have an assigned department.

#### Set Difference

The set difference of teachers and departments, `teacher \ department` would be a kind of "anti-join"

```
SELECT
t.name
FROM teacher t
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.id = t.dept_id
WHERE d.id IS NULL
```

At first glance, this statement does what your statement does, *if the foreign key reference was enforced, it would guarantee to do exactly that*. However, one use for this statement would be to retrieve teachers who are assigned to departments that have since been deleted (e.g. if the English Lit Dept. & English as 2nd Lang Dept. were reorganized as the English Dept.)

#### Symmetric Difference

Another "anti-join" would be the symmetric difference, which selects elements from both sets **ONLY** if they cannot be joined, i.e

```
(teacher \ department) U (department \ teacher)
```

I can't think of a motivating example using teachers and departments, but one way to write the symmetric difference on databases that support the FULL OUTER JOIN would be:

```
SELECT
t.name
FROM teacher t
FULL OUTER JOIN department d ON d.id = t.dept_id
WHERE d.id IS NULL OR t.id IS NULL
```

For MySQL, this statement would have to be written as the union of two statements.

```
SELECT
t.name teacher_name, d.name department_name
FROM teacher t
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.id = t.dept_id
WHERE d.id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
t.name teacher_name, d.name department_name
FROM teacher t
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.id = t.dept_id
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Looking through one of my projects, I found this one use of symmetric difference:

**Context:**

> I have three tables: `users`, `users_gameplay_summary`, `users_transactions_summary`. I needed to email those users who created their accounts in the past 7 days **AND** one of the following
>   `have transacted but have not played` or `played but have not transacted.`

To get the list, I have this query (note, this was written for Postgresql, and won't work on MySQL, but it illustrates the symmetric difference use case):

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(g.user_id, t.user_id) user_id
FROM users_gameplay_summary g
FULL OUTER JOIN users_transactions_summary t ON t.user_id = g.user_id

WHERE COALESCE(g.user_id, t.user_id) IN (
          SELECT user_id 
          FROM users 
          WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - '7 day'::interval)
  AND (g.user_id IS NULL OR t.user_id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, your not actually joining anything now,
in the case of a left anti join you would have access to the department name as well. (although it would be NULL)

Your sql code would be a correct answer for the question you gave though.

A left anti join would be:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM teacher t
LEFT JOIN dept d ON d.id = t.dept
WHERE d.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Why do an it makes me wonder why do an expensive join, if a simple select would suffice?

Comment: in your case you wouldn't. i'm just giving it as an example.
I think you're wondering why you would ever do a anti join instead of IS NULL? and at the moment i'm wondering with you xD

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem of listing teachers without assigned departments, you don't need a `JOIN` between `teacher` and `dept` tables.

`dept` table is basically a dictionary table that you join to, to translate ids to corresponding names.

`teacher` table has a `dept` column which normally could have a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to `id` column in `dept` table.

---

Your query is not an ANTI-JOIN. This is a simple [projection and selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031076/what-are-projection-and-selection) query using one table.

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM teacher t
WHERE t.dept IS NULL
```

For an `ANTI-JOIN` you would at least need a JOIN operation between more than one table at first.

Normally an `ANTI-JOIN` could look like:

> Using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.join_column = t2.join_column
WHERE t2.join_column IS NULL
```

> Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t1.join_column = t2.join_column
  )
```