# Is it possible to eliminate PROJECTION operator when optimizing an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-optimization

For an SQL query:

```
select * from t where R
```

we'll first optimize the ast built from this SQL, and get a logical plan, like
Projection  -- > Selection -- > t

Is it possible to eliminate the PROJECTION part?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [What are projection and selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031076/what-are-projection-and-selection) SO topic, projection

> means choosing which columns (or expressions) the query shall return

Therefore, this step can hardly be skipped.