# List to list conversion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, wcf, c#-4.0

Is this mapping correct? The list can have multiple rows

I am very curious to know if say the list contains 3 rows, and all 3 rows will be mapped? Or do we need a looping?

```
public List<Data> DataDetails { get; set; }

public static DataDetails ToDataConvert ( this Datadto data)
{

 DataDetails = dto.DataDetails.Select(x => new Data()
                        {
                            Name = x.Name,
                            id = x.Id
                        })
                        .ToList()
}
```

Comment: Does it compile?  That's often a very good sign.  A LINQ `.Select` operation is a _projection_, it selects the columns of data you are interested in, but returns all rows.  Somewhat confusingly, a LINQ `.Where` operation is a _selection_, picking out which rows should be in the result.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031076/what-are-projection-and-selection

Comment: The return type of this method should be List<Data> instead of DataDetails.

Comment: This code will not compile, and its wrong on several levels, we cant help you as this is not your real attempt or real code

Comment: @Xiaosu: Thank you, I have the good code, but just wanna double check if what I am doing (MY intention is map list to list) is correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is this came from `dto` (dto.DataDetails)

This `dto.DataDetails` Depends on how many rows you have created.

Your Code:

```
DataDetails = dto.DataDetails.Select(x => new Data
                        {
                            Name = x.Name,
                            id = x.Id
                        })
                        .ToList()
```

Your `DataDetails` Depends on this `public List<Data> DataDetails { get; set; }` the `Data` List

As a Result of your `DataDetails` Depend on this part of code:

```
     {
         Name = x.Name,
          id = x.Id
     })
```

If Your `Data` Class look like this

```
public String Name {get;set;}
public int id{get;set;}
public String Address {get;set;}
```

This means you did not include the `Address` of your `Data` Class as an example.
As a Result you can get an `Address` but it returns a value of null.

Now if your linq looks like this:

```
dto.DataDetails.ToList()
```

this will include all the records you wanted to get but you need to use this class `DataDetails` as your variable something like:

```
VarFromDataDetailsClass =  dto.DataDetails.ToList();
```

or

```
var Result =  dto.DataDetails.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use extension method in c# and convert a list.
If so, I suggest you could use your converted list as the return value of your method. My extension method convert object of type List

```
namespace ServiceInterface.Models
{
public static  class ExtensionClass
{

    public static List<Customer> ConvertCustomer(this List<Customer> customers)
    {
        return customers.Select(
            c =>

            new Customer
            {
                FirstName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                LastName = "",
                Gender = c.Gender
            }).ToList();
    }
}
}
```

Then you could write use the extension method as follows. Please don't forget to import the namespace of your extension method.

```
using ServiceInterface.Models;
namespace consoleClient.Message_exe
{
    class StringTest
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
             List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer{LastName="a", FirstName="b"},
            new Customer{LastName="c", FirstName="d"}
        };

    }
}
```

The result.

[image]