# How to conditionally retreive the first occurrence of subarray record from json array based on a sibling column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a mysql database with table `orders`, where all installments are kept in one column called installmentData

example record looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "amount": "79.00",
        "paid_at": "2019-07-24",
        "payment_date": "2019-07-27"
    },
    {
        "amount": "80.00",
        "paid_at": false,
        "payment_date": "2019-08-27"
    },
    {
        "amount": "80.00",
        "paid_at": false,
        "payment_date": "2019-09-27"
    }
]
```

What I would like to get is the first record of `payment_date` from json where `paid_at` is false

I tried something like this

```sql
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(installmentData, '$[*].paid_at') as paidArray,
    JSON_EXTRACT(installmentData, '$[*].payment_date') as dateArray
FROM 
    orders 
WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(installmentData, '$[*].paid_at'), 'false') IS TRUE 
AND 
    resignation IS FALSE 
ORDER BY `orders`.`status` DESC
```

this query return this

```
["2019-07-24", false, false]    ["2019-07-27", "2019-08-27, 2019-09-27]
```

and I want to only return

```
[false] ["2019-08-27"]
```

Is it possible to get that specific value in the example above?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? You would have to do it with `JSON_TABLE()`, but that function is not implemented in past versions of MySQL before 8.0.

Comment: I posted an answer for a similar case here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55809822/20860

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I'm using mysql 5.7 so i'll have to upgrade mysql and test it.

Comment: It would be better if you could store data in normal columns, which would be far more efficient, more compact, and easier to write queries for. If you're using JSON search functions in your `WHERE` clause, that's an indication that you've designed your database wrong.

Comment: this is just for migrations to update order statuses