# Mysql JSON, Find and replace value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table that contains product price and stock by size and color. I put them in JSON format. Table structure like

```
id | chart
---+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1  | [{"size":"XL", "color":"Red", "stock":"30", "price":"300"},  |
   |  {"size":"XXL", "color":"Red", "stock":"40", "price":"400"}, |
   |  {"size":"XXL", "color":"Blue", "stock":"35", "price":"450"}]|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to update the price value to 350, If the size match with **XL** and the Color with **Red**. I tried this code,

```
UPDATE t
SET chart = REGEXP_REPLACE(
  JSON_EXTRACT(chart, '$'), 
  JSON_OBJECT("size", "XL", "color", "Red", "stock", "([0-9]+)", "price", "([0-9]+)"),
  JSON_OBJECT("size", "XL", "color", "Red", "stock", "$1", "price", "350")
)
WHERE id = 1;
```

It executes successfully. But the main problem is stock value changes with **$1** string. Here it should be updated with previous stock value which is unknown to me.

Comment: Any chance the schema could be refactored so the tables are at least in a 1st normal form?

Comment: @Serg I'm sorry, I can't understand. Please write in details

Comment: There are JSON functions for modifying JSON data, don't use a regular expression.

Comment: @Barmar can you please solve this problem with JSON function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809822/mysql-search-json-value-by-key-in-array for how to find an object in a JSON array by key value.  Then use `JSON_REPLACE()` to replace the price.

Comment: I'm not going to try to solve it myself because the JSON functions are too confusing. I would never think of using the JSON datatype because this is so hard.

Comment: I advice creating a separate table `Chart(productId, size, color, stock, price)` to store your data. This way you can easilly update whatever you want.

Comment: JSON_TABLE > REPLACE + WHERE > JSON_ARRAYAGG