# Break SQL query into parts for accessing content provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have an SQL query from string and trying to access `ContentProvider`. The sql query looks like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM application_settings WHERE _id = ?";
```

I have to access content provider by gettting `ContentResolver` like:

```
context.getContentResolver().query()
```

but query method accepts:

```
Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder);
```

Is there a way I can split the string query into projection, selection, selectionArgs and sortOrder?

I do not wish to execute raw queries so I would prefer to have a solution for this function with bind values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just written a library which provides what you need. You only need to copy and paste it into the project and if you would like to add, expand and customize it depending on your requirements.

### SqliteHandler.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

class SqliteHandler {
// VERY IMPORTANT MAKE SURE IT'S CORRECT AND REGISTERED IN THE MANIFEST
private String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.android.mySqlite";
private String CONTENT_URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/";
private Context context;

SqliteHandler(Context context, String PROVIDER_NAME) {
    this.context = context;
    this.PROVIDER_NAME = PROVIDER_NAME;
}

Cursor exeQuery(String query) {
    try {
        queryObject obj = convertQueryStringToQueryObject(query);
        return context.getContentResolver().query(obj.uri, obj.projection, obj.selection, obj.selectionArgs, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

Cursor exeQuery(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {
    try {
        queryObject obj = convertQueryStringToQueryObject(query);
        return context.getContentResolver().query(obj.uri, obj.projection, obj.selection, selectionArgs, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

Cursor exeQuery(String query, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    try {
        queryObject obj = convertQueryStringToQueryObject(query);
        return context.getContentResolver().query(obj.uri, obj.projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

Cursor exeQuery(String query, String[] projection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    try {
        queryObject obj = convertQueryStringToQueryObject(query);
        return context.getContentResolver().query(obj.uri, projection, obj.selection, selectionArgs, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

Cursor exeQuery(queryObject obj) {
    try {
        return context.getContentResolver().query(obj.uri, obj.projection, obj.selection, obj.selectionArgs, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


class queryObject {
    Uri uri;
    String[] projection;
    String selection;
    String[] selectionArgs;
    String sortOrder;

    queryObject(String table_name, String[] projection, String selection, String[]
            selectionArgs) {
        this.uri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URL + table_name);
        this.projection = projection;
        this.selection = selection;
        this.selectionArgs = selectionArgs;
    }
}

queryObject convertQueryStringToQueryObject(String query) {
    try {
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        String[] s = query.split("select")[1].split("from");
        String[] projection = s[0].split(",");
        String[] s2 = s[1].split("where");
        String table_name = s2[0];
        String logText = "";
        if (s2.length > 1) {
            selection = s2[1];
            String[] args = s2[1].split("=");
            selectionArgs = new String[args.length - 1];// half of the args are values others are keys
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                selectionArgs[count] = args[i]
                        .split("and")[0]
                        .split("or")[0]
                        .replace(" ", "")
                        .replace("and", "")
                        .replace("or", "");
                count++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < selectionArgs.length; i++) {
                logText += selectionArgs[i];
                if (i < selectionArgs.length - 1) logText += ",";
                selection = selection.replace(selectionArgs[i], "?");
            }
        }
        Log.i("table_name", table_name);
        Log.i("selection: ", selection == null ? "null" : selection);
        Log.i("selectionArgs", logText.equals("") ? "null" : logText);
        logText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < projection.length; i++) {
            logText += projection[i];
            if (i < projection.length - 1) logText += ",";
        }
        Log.i("projection", logText);
        return new queryObject(table_name, projection, selection, selectionArgs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}}
```

### How To Use

instantiate `SqliteHandler`, it's very important to pass valid `PROVIDER_NAME` and also make sure that your `CONTENT_PROVIDER` was registered in the `AndroidManiFest.xml`. For an illustration of how does it work, we pass three different queries and get return values which are objects of type `queryObject`

```
SqliteHandler sh = new SqliteHandler(this,"PROVIDER_NAME");
SqliteHandler.queryObject obj1 = sh.convertQueryStringToQueryObject("SELECT * FROM table_name");
SqliteHandler.queryObject obj2 = sh.convertQueryStringToQueryObject("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE _id = ?");
SqliteHandler.queryObject obj3 = sh.convertQueryStringToQueryObject("SELECT param1,param2,param3 FROM table_name WHERE param1 =\"a\" and param2=\"b\" or param3=\"c\"");
```

The method `convertQueryStringToQueryObject` converts `query string` into `query class` then we can use this class for `getContentResolver().query()`.

---

**Important Note**: because `getContentResolver().query()` needs `Uri`. Therefore, we need to create a `Uri` from the `table_name`. As a result, we need to pass valid `PROVIDER_NAME` to the instance of `SqliteHandler`.

---

### Output Log

As you can see the three different queries broke apart into parameters which we can use in the `getContentResolver().query()`

```
// 1th query 
I/table_name:  table_name
I/selection:: null
I/selectionArgs: null
I/projection:  * 
// 2th query 
I/table_name:  table_name 
I/selection::  _id = ?
I/selectionArgs: ?
I/projection:  * 
// 3th query 
I/table_name:  table_name 
I/selection::  param1 =? and param2=? or param3=?
I/selectionArgs: "a","b","c"
I/projection:  param1,param2,param3
```

### Complete Example

in The `SqliteHandler.java` there is the `exeQuery` method which has several overloads. Moreover, You can have a `Cursor` at the `Content Provider` depending on different input parameters.

```
SqliteHandler sh = new SqliteHandler(this,"PROVIDER_NAME");
SqliteHandler.queryObject obj1 = sh.convertQueryStringToQueryObject("SELECT * FROM table_name");
SqliteHandler.queryObject obj2 = sh.convertQueryStringToQueryObject("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE _id = ?");
SqliteHandler.queryObject obj3 = sh.convertQueryStringToQueryObject("SELECT param1,param2,param3 FROM table_name WHERE param1 =\"a\" and param2=\"b\" or param3=\"c\"");
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery(obj1);
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery(obj2);
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery(obj3);
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery("SELECT param1,param2,param3 FROM table_name WHERE param1 =\"a\" and param2=\"b\" or param3=\"c\"");
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE _id = ?",new String[]{"whereArg"});
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name"," _id = ? ",new String[]{"whereArg"});
Cursor c = sh.exeQuery("SELECT ? FROM table_name WHERE _id = ?",new String[]{"Field"},new String[]{"whereArg"});
```

However, if you don't want to use `exeQuery` try below walking through:

```
queryObject obj = convertQueryStringToQueryObject(query);
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(obj.uri, obj.projection, obj.selection, obj.selectionArgs, null);
```

Comment: even though your answer eventually works there is definitely a lot of space for improvements as this can crash in a lot of places.  But the result is that it works so thank you for the answer

Comment: @matrix your welcome and i made a repository in github to issue bugs and crashes.i will be gald to contribute on it. https://github.com/MrAshFar/SqliteHandler

Answer (score -1):

from the android document https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#ClientProvider

> ```
> cursor = getContentResolver().query(
>     UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
>     projection,                        // The columns to return for each row
>     selectionClause,                   // Selection criteria
>     selectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
>     sortOrder);                        // The sort order for the returned rows
> ```

you can do this

```
String[] projection = {"*"};
String[] selectionArgs = {"1", "2"}; //your ids here
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://your_provider/your_table"), projection, "_id", selectionArgs, null);
cursor.close();
```

to create provider see this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating#top_of_page

see this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031101/10989990

Comment: this is not what I asked